# Android app crashing when opening activity after another

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities "ListmenuActivity" and "SearchmenuActivity", For some odd reason, when I open up the app from fresh, and then open the crashing activity("SearchmenuActivity"), it doesn't crash and works as it should. On the other hand, when I open up the app and then open up the "ListmenuActivity" that holds mulitple EditText's, once I click on one of the EditText's that then opens up a ListView. When I try to go back and open up the "SearchmenuActivity" the app crashes after I've opened up the "ListmenuActivity.

I'm not sure why this happens, if someone could help out, would be much appreciated.

Here's the LOG:

```
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.youtube.iamjackpot/com.youtube.iamjackpot.SearchmenuActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at com.youtube.iamjackpot.SearchmenuActivity.onCreate(SearchmenuActivity.java:13)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    ... 11 more
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    ... 23 more
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3373)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3310)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:454)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:189)
08-16 11:02:18.928: E/AndroidRuntime(24989):    ... 26 more
```

Main activity I open "SearchmenuActivity" and "ListmenuActivity" from :

```
package com.youtube.iamjackpot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Search Button:
    ImageView SearchButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
    SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent searchmenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SearchmenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(searchmenu);

        }
    });
    // List Button
    ImageView ListButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ListButton);
    ListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent listmenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ListmenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(listmenu);

        }
    });
    // Popular Button
    ImageView HotButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.HotButton);
    HotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent popmenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HotmenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(popmenu);
        }
    });
    // Info Button
    ImageView InfoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.InfoButton);
    InfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent infomenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    InfomenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(infomenu);
        }
    });
}
}
```

SearchmenuActivity:

```
package com.youtube.iamjackpot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SearchmenuActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchmenu);

    String ComponentList[] = {

    "List", "List", "List", "List" };

    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoCompleteTextViewSearch);
    actv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.componentlistdetail, ComponentList));

};

}
```

ListmenuActivity:

```
package com.youtube.iamjackpot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListmenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listmenu);

    EditText CPU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4);
    CPU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent CPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CPUList, 1);

        }
    });

    EditText RAMList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    RAMList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent RAMList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RAMList.class);
            startActivityForResult(RAMList, 2);

        }
    });

    EditText GPUList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView3);
    GPUList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent GPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    GPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(GPUList, 3);

        }
    });

    EditText MOBOList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
    MOBOList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent MOBOList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MOBOList.class);
            startActivityForResult(MOBOList, 4);

        }
    });

    EditText CASEList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView7);
    CASEList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent CASEList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CASEList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CASEList, 5);

        }
    });

    EditText HDDList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView6);
    HDDList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent HDDList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HDDList.class);
            startActivityForResult(HDDList, 6);
        }
    });

    EditText PSUList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView9);
    PSUList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent PSUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PSUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(PSUList, 7);
        }
    });

    EditText SSDList = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView8);
    SSDList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent SSDList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SSDList.class);
            startActivityForResult(SSDList, 8);

        }
    });

    final Button SearchListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SearchListButton);
    SearchListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent OpenDisplayDataActivity = new Intent(
                    ListmenuActivity.this, ListMenuDisplayData.class);
            OpenDisplayDataActivity.putExtra("productCPU",
                    SearchListButton.getText());
            startActivity(OpenDisplayDataActivity);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {


    } else if (requestCode == 1) {
        Intent a = getIntent();
        String productCPU = data.getStringExtra("productCPU");
        EditText CPU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4));
        CPU.setText(productCPU);
    } else if (requestCode == 2) {
        // Handle result of RAMList
        Intent b = getIntent();
        String productRAM = data.getStringExtra("productRAM");
        EditText RAM = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1));
        RAM.setText(productRAM);
    } else if (requestCode == 3) {
        // handle result of GPU
        Intent c = new Intent();
        String productGPU = data.getStringExtra("productGPU");
        EditText GPU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView3));
        GPU.setText(productGPU);
    } else if (requestCode == 4) {
        Intent d = new Intent();
        String productMOBO = data.getStringExtra("productMOBO");
        EditText MOBO = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2));
        MOBO.setText(productMOBO);
    } else if (requestCode == 5) {
        Intent e = new Intent();
        String productCASE = data.getStringExtra("productCASE");
        EditText CASE = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView7));
        CASE.setText(productCASE);
    } else if (requestCode == 6) {

        Intent f = new Intent();
        String productHDD = data.getStringExtra("productHDD");
        EditText HDD = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView6));
        HDD.setText(productHDD);

    } else if (requestCode == 7) {
        Intent g = new Intent();
        String productPSU = data.getStringExtra("productPSU");
        EditText PSU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView9));
        PSU.setText(productPSU);

    } else if (requestCode == 8) {
        Intent h = new Intent();
        String productSSD = data.getStringExtra("productSSD");
        EditText SSD = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView8));
        SSD.setText(productSSD);

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}



}
```

Comment: probably because you are trying to reload activity which contains this library "com.youtube.iamjackpot/com" again which inflate the xml ,but if you go for it first time it won't crash at all

Comment: It's saying 'OutOfMemoryError'. So You use some big resolution images for backgrounds? Have You checked heap size in DDMS?

Comment: at com.youtube.iamjackpot.SearchmenuActivity.onCreate(SearchmenuActivity.java:13)- is the line where error is there, what is there on that line?

Comment: How are the various '...list' variables instantiated?

Comment: First try replacing `            Intent searchmenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SearchmenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(searchmenu);` with `            Intent searchmenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SearchmenuActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(searchmenu);`

Comment: @g00dy It's still crashing when I use that code.

Comment: I've managed to find the cause of the problem, it's because of the background. When I remove the background from the "SearchmenyActivity's XML file, it doesn't crash. Maybe I should try and use a different image output?

Comment: @sandrstar if you read my comment above, it's something to do with the  background. How do I check the heap size in DDMS? thanks

Comment: DDMS has heap tracker panel. However, I've faced the same issues before and only wayout I've found was to remove big pictures from background.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.youtube.iamjackpot;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ImageView SearchButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent searchmenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
SearchmenuActivity.class);
startActivity(searchmenu);

}
});
```

Comment: in manifest file please specify all the activity which u are using in this project.

Comment: I've managed to find the cause of the problem, it's because of the background. When I remove the background from the "SearchmenyActivity's XML file, it doesn't crash. Maybe I should try and use a different image output?

Comment: okey you can try but above code will be update..which i give n you...if u will get failure again then post your whole code xml and manifest and java file i will update it give proper solution for that code